# How to implement ancestor or any other way to retrieve recent updates in Google App engine (Java)? I have to use single entity only..,

Tags: java, google-app-engine

```
Query q = new Query("Employees");
q.addFilter("is_active", FilterOperator.EQUAL, isActive);
q.addSort("first_name", SortDirection.ASCENDING);
```

and

```
Employees employee = ofy().load().type(Employees.class).id("123").get();
```

These type of queries are used for retrieve data from datastore, but i can't get the recent updates.

Comment: If i am right, then you need the recently modified entities from Datastore?

Comment: yes..., If am update any field sometimes it gives last update only (what i did in before modification).., not recent update..,

Comment: Are you asked to use only Low Level Api of Datastore, Not JDO?

Comment: Low level Api only.., not any JDO or JPA

Answer (score 0):

For datastore queries with range and offset, you can use

```
Query q = new Query("Employees");
q.addFilter("is_active", FilterOperator.EQUAL, isActive);
q.addSort("first_name", SortDirection.ASCENDING);

PreparedQuery pq          =  datastore.prepare(q);
List<Employees> result    =  pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withOffset(5).limit(5));
```

where you can specify the offset from where you need to fetch and limit is the number of results to be fetched

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a solution to eventual consistency. To get strong consistency on a query, you need to be using an ancestor query, which requires having an ancestor key.

Read about [strong consistency here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency)

In terms of objectify, fetch by id is always strongly consistent. Queries will be strongly consistent if you take the following approach:

```
List<Employee> employees = ofy()
          .load()
          .type(Employee.class)
          .ancestor(parentKey)
          .filter("field", value)
          .list()
```

Note that when making an eventually consistent query (i.e. an non-ancestor query) with objectify  the contents of entities returned by objectify will be correct (i.e. consistent and up to date), however the entities returned will be the result of an eventually consistent query.

To achieve your goal, you will need to partition employees on some axis, and use that as the ancestor key. The main issue you will face is that there is a limit of one write per second on an entity group.

You also do not need an entity for the parent, just a key. It does not need to exist itself in the datastore as an entry.